# Access spockframework data variables in setup method

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, spock

I've a data-driven test:

```
def "#testDB : create customer using the caller interface"(){
    given:
        TestUtils.install(testDB)
        caller = new Caller(testDB.dbInterface.dataSource())

        def firstName = "Abdullah"
        def lastName = "Mohammad"

    when:
        def custId = caller.call("create_customer", params(of(firstName, VARCHAR), of(lastName, VARCHAR)),
            paramTypes(INTEGER), {it.getInt(1)});
    then:
        custId == custIdFromDb
    cleanup:
        TestUtils.rollback(testDB)
    where:
        testDB << testDBs
        custIdFromDb << [0, 1]
}
```

Is it possible to separate the first two lines in the given block into `setup()`:

```
TestUtils.install(testDB)
caller = new Caller(testDB.dbInterface.dataSource())
```

and the cleanup block into `cleanup` method?

Full test case can [found at gihub](https://github.com/mhewedy/spwrap/blob/master/src/test/groovy/spwrap/CallerIntTest.groovy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because what you define in your `where:` block is only locally available from within the corresponding feature method and is thus to be managed inside the method. So the initialisation is well kept inside the `given:` section (or `setup:`, which is just an alias) and the clean-up inside the `cleanup:` section.

The `setup()` and `cleanup()` methods however are executed for each single feature method in your specification class, i.e. those should only be used for data which are common to all feature methods and need to be initialised everytime a feature is executed, in contrast to `@Shared` variables which would rather be initialised in `setupSpec()`.